# How to unserialise big object (~10mb) into memory on Android?

Tags: java, android, stack-overflow

I have trained my neural network on local PC, and when I am trying to load that NN into android device I am getting stack overflow error. Size of that NN object is around 10mb. Is there any way of me loading that whole object?

I've tried changing extension to mp3, I also added **android:largeHeap="true"** and nothing seems to work.

Comment: How are you trying to load the data?  It doesn't sound like an OOM situation, and more like a coding error (since you're getting a "stack overflow")

Comment: Can you include the Logcat of stackoverflow error?

Comment: Please include the exception trace and the model into which you want to deserialize your NN.